# AdMob plugin add to cordova returns error

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, admob, cordova-plugins

I'm trying to add the AdMob plugin for cordova in my ionic project but I'm getting the following error:

> Error: Registry returned 404 for GET on https://registry.npmjs.org/com.rjfun.cordova.plugin.admob

The comand I use is:

```
cordova plugin add com.rjfun.cordova.plugin.admob
```

Any ideas why this happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with

```
cordova plugin add cordova-admob
```

See instructions in [this repo](https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-cordova)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-plugin-admob
```

[Read More](https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-plugin-admob)

Comment: now I'm getting the following error:

Error: Registry returned 404 for GET on https://registry.npmjs.org/com.google.admobsdk